ref is null inside onmounted() in vue 3 script setup
trying to get parent element of router-view, and show some background animation. but ref is null inside onmounted(), used nextTick() still ref is null. if i use watch with fogElement.value is not null, but how to do it using onmounted()?
<script>
    const fogElement = ref(null);
    onMounted(async () => {
      await nextTick();
      console.log(fogElement.value)
    })
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <div class="fill-height bg-tertiary" ref="fogElement">
        <router-view/>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>


Hi, Its something related to vuetify, I would suggest to wrap the v-app in a div and add ref on that div.

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Generally template elements are expected to be there after nextTick but this won't work if they are mounted asynchronously. This will naturally happen is suspense is in use, which will take place with async view comps. If you want  to be instantly mounted, you likely have to use  explicitly to limit the point to which it propagates to the comps that are parent to . This is probably XY problem as suspense is intended for loading indicators

If <script>, instead of <script setup> is not a typo, you should define and expose fogElement in export default { setup() { /* here */ } }
